# what difference between NULL, blank and empty in php?

Tags: php

i have one form which have  some input box and some select box.
i want to apply that nothing can be empty or blank before further activity,
so i use below condition

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v=='' || $v==NULL || empty($v))
    {
        $_SESSION['errMsg']=' Please fill all the fields properly';
                    header("location:somepage.php");
                    exit;
    }
     }
```

now my question is:

above `if` is useful or not?

if not then which condition is enough to prevent blank entry `$v==''` or `$v==NULL` or `empty($v)` or i have to use all of these conditions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean `$v == ''` instead of `'$v=='`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`empty()` should take care of all those.

From the manual:

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

And the very handy [Type-Comparison Table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 1):

Mike already described when `emtpy()` evaluates to `true`.
But note this:

- Every value in `$_POST` is a string anyway, so comparing it to `NULL` is unnecessary.
- **If a field is allowed to have the value `0`**, you have to **treat it differently** as `empty()` will return `true` for this value too!

Comment: so what i have to do sir? please suggest me fullproof idea

Answer (score 1):

PHP function `empty()` checks for everything you asked for. You also might consider form fields being empty, if they contain only whitespaces or line breaks. Avoid this by adding `trim()`.

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    if (empty(trim($v))) {
        //...
    }
}
```