# Why isset(null) throws an error but empty(null) not?

Tags: php

I just came across a strange situation. When I try the following code in `$ php -a`, I receive an error:

```
php > var_dump(isset(null));
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression
>   (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php shell code on line
>   1

But when I do the same thing with empty(), everything is ok:

```
php > var_dump(empty(null));
bool(true)
```

Can anyone explain why I receive an error when I try `isset(null)`?

---

**Update**

Thank you all for your answers. I asked this question just to make sense of why `isset()` is behaving differently from `empty()`.

To me, both of them are php functions and both accept a parameter. So, as any other function in php, calling `isset(null)` should be a valid statement. Aren't we passing null as a value to isset() function? So why php consider it as an expression?

Comment: Probably because null is/can be empty and isset checks if something is set and needs to compare with something; that's my take on it. Here, have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615747/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-empty

Comment: If you do `isset(null);` you get this error - but what's the point anyway of doing that anyway? If you do `$var = null; var_dump(isset($var));` instead, that would be valid and produce `bool(false)`, because then you're dealing with a *variable* and not an expression (see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: Obviously, nobody "answered" the question. *(so far).* I need no upvoted comments or answer accepted.

Comment: This shold be fairly obvious if you read the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing if an expression is "set" doesn't make sense. [As per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), `isset` is used to

> Determine if a **variable** is set and is not NULL.

If you want to check if an expression is null, use `is_null`, or as the error message suggests, `null !== expression`.

[The manual for empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) suggests something similar:

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty.

until you read slightly further down, in the changelog:

> **5.5.0** empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.

Prior to this, `empty(null)` would have thrown an error along the lines of

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in ... on line ...

Comment: The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) says the same thing about empty: "Determine whether a **variable** is considered to be empty.". But it seems empty() accepts expressions while isset() does not.

Comment: @ArminSam So it does, I've just realised that the important part of the question is the ambiguity between the two. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: But why would php consider null, or any other value for that matter, as expression? We are calling a function called `isset` and passing parameter `null` to it. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @ArminSam - an expression means something that *produces* the value, after it's evaluated - `null`, constants, functions - they are all some sort of an expression which ultimately produces something. A `null` is a special **value**, meaning that it's an expression and not a *variable*. `isset` expects a variable, while `empty` can work with expressions. You can't check if an expression is set, it doesn't make much sense to do so because - well, it's set since its value is present. You check whether **variables** are set.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for the explanation. I also found why isset is not behaving like a normal function, ... because [**it's not a function**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)! It's a language construct like `echo`, `die`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found something that I didn't know before in php which could be the answer to this question. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), `isset()` **is not a function**, but rather a **language construct** like `if ... else`, `foreach` and `while`:

> **Note**: Because this [referring to isset()] is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using [variable
>   functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

There are a few more of these language constructs that can be easily confused with functions, including:

- unset()
- empty()
- die()
- include()

So now it makes sense why `isset(null)` doesn't work. We are trying to use a construct that expects a **variable** inside the parenthesis. Providing anything else other than a variable will result in **syntax error** during parsing of the code.