# Should I use truthy approach rather than is_null, isset, or empty?

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to PHP and this is probably a stupid question or very basic at best. My boss keeps on telling us to use truthy approach for setting variables rather than using is_null, isset, or empty.

Example:

```
$res = !is_null($response) ? $response : $this->response;
```

He argued it would be better to be like or similar.

```
$res = $this->response;
if($response) {
   $res = $response;
}
```

Just want to hear from the community what is generally or best approach for this matter. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the expected data. What are you trying to determine about the value? Also see [PHP type comparison tables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: @showdev in that case just a simple null or not null.

Comment: If you are specifically checking whether a value is NULL, I'd use `is_null`. If you want to determine whether a string is not empty or whether a value is "truthy", you might use a different approach. Also see [what difference between NULL, blank and empty in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461239/what-difference-between-null-blank-and-empty-in-php).

Comment: Ok got it @showdev thanks!